# How to Show Listview Conent in New Page Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have XML Service, Which i have Parsed and Got Response From Service. Next I have took the Response and Added to Listview from Jquery Mobile.I have Successfully Populated List View with Some Details and one Sample Image in it. My Problem is When i have Clicked on list Item i have to show data regarding to the list item. Say I have Clicked the Second List Item then Second List Item Should be Shown in New Page.What i have Tried is.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://api.geonames.org/children?geonameId=3175395&username=tutorialsgeek",
          dataType: "xml",
          success: xmlParser,
          error: function(errorThrown) {
              alert("An error occurred!" + errorThrown);
          }
      });
  });

  function xmlParser(data) {
      xml = data;
      var imageLink = "https://hca.twimg.com/a/1380571156/gazebo/img/bg-hero.jpg";
      $('#load').fadeOut();
      $(xml).find('geonames geoname').each(function(index, val) {
          var output = "";
          var locationName = $(this).find("toponymName").text();
          var name = $(this).find("name").text();
          output += '<li>';
          output += '<a href="#blogpost">';
          output += '<h3>';
          output += locationName;
          output += '</h3>';
          output += '<img src="' + imageLink + '" alt="image" />';
          output += '<p>';
          output += 'name :' + name;
          output += '</p></a>';
          output += '</li>';
          $("#list").append(output);
           $('#list').listview('refresh');
      });     
  }
```

and my html page is..

```
<div data-role="page" id="listPage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>XMl Parsing</h1>
    </div><!--End of header-->

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="result">
            <ul data-filter="true" data-role="listview" data-theme="c" id=
            "list">
                <li id="load">Loading Data...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--end of content-->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="blogpost">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>XMl Parsing</h1>
    </div><!--End of header-->

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div><!--end of content-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an event to all hyperlinks in your list and handle code for displaying more information there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').on('click', 'a', function() {
        //display more information
    });
});
```

To pass along the *geonameid*, you could add a data-attribute to the link before adding it to the DOM

```
var geonameId = $(this).find("geonameId").text();
output += '<a href="#blogpost" data-geonameid="'+geonameId+'">';
```

Then, in your event handler, you could easily retreive it when the event is fired

```
$('#list').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var geonameId = $(this).data('geonameid');
    //display more information using your new, shiny geonameId
});
```

Comment: I expanded my answer to include what you may be after.

Comment: ok Thanks but...I am actually IOS Developer. In Ios we add all xml data to array then add it to the tableview. when list item is clicked, we call by object at index of array to populate a new screen with Respective data . Can you please check this what i want to make http://www.moretechtips.net/2012/07/dynamic-page-generation-in-jquery.html

Comment: I must say that I totally missed that this was regarding jQuery mobile and, as I'm not familiar with it, I don't know if my answer works. However, I'm sure the same general idea applies. I don't know what you want me to do with that link, though.

Comment: Can you say me How to add all xml data to Array and it has to be appended to listview. Then When i click on list item lets say second, Object at index 1 of Array Details should displayed in Alert..